# Laravel Database Updates with form data

Tags: php, mysql, forms, laravel

All,

Just trying to see what the best option would be to update a database row with data submitted in a form. I understand the Laravel update query builder, but I am stumped on how to get form data, and then to execute that query. Relatively new to Laravel :) Here is what I had come up with, just from my PHP experience and logic:

I had tried to put the query into a function and then have the form action be that funtion:

```
function editsop(){
       // query
    }
```

Like I said, main problem is trying to get the named form objects to be the thing that will update the row. I have 2 text input fields, respectively named "body" and "notes." So the data there would be what is updated into the DB. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function editsop(Request $request){

// this below allows you to get the value of the input from the form
regardless if its a post or get


$request->input('name of input from form');

    }
```

this has all the details you'll need

[laravel 5.3 Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests)

Comment: So I would essentially request the form data, then set it as a variable then do the query?

Comment: if you had a from with "body" and "notes" fields, you would submit that form via post or get, on the page receiving the from, your function would be called, Check the link i linked its right from the manual and explains it better